# If $V$ is a vector space $\neq$ the vector space of its additive identity alone, must $V$ have a subspace $\neq V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems to me highly plausible that every vector space $V$ such that $V$ does not consist of the additive identity alone has a (nontrivial) subspace $\neq V$. But I have not yet seen a way to prove or disprove this proposition.

Is it true or false?

Comment: Well, after the 0-dimensional vector space, what's the next smallest vector space?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks. I am not aware of "the next smallest vector space"?

Comment: @Chou If you think about it geometrically, finite dimensional vector spaces (and their subspaces, which are also finite dimensional) have finite sets of elements called *bases*.  A basis for a vector space is a set of elements that is linearly independent and spans the vector space.  The number of elements in the basis is the dimension of the space.  You can pretend that if a vector space has 1 basis element, then it is a "line" (this is true in Euclidean space $\Bbb R^{n}$, but not in other spaces -- but we can still intuitively imagine it as a line).

Comment: @Chou Then a vector space with two basis elements can be thought of as a plane.  So Zhen Lin's comment was saying: since we are assuming $V$ is not just the $0$-dimensional vector space, it has to have dimension at least 1.  Suppose it has dimension 1.  Any non-zero subspace will have to contain one of the original basis elements of $V$.  If $V$ has dimension 1, then any non-zero subspace will HAVE to have the same basis element that spans all of $V$, so that subspace must equal $V$.  So $V$ has *no* non-trivial subspaces, but it does have a subspace, as the $0$-subspace is one.

Comment: If we move into higher dimensions, such as $2$-dimensions, then we can *always* find a proper non-trivial subspace.  Just take one of the basis elements and look at its span.  This will be a proper subspace since it doesn't contain any other basis elements, and it will be non-trivial since there is more than just $0$ in it.

Comment: @Chou: I guess you mean subspaces other than the trivial subspace consisting of $0$ alone, right? Because that's a subspace of every vector space...

Comment: @MPW Thanks; yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want nontrivial subspaces --- if $V$ does not equal $\{0\}$, then there exists some nonzero $v\in V$. Then Span($v$) is a nontrivial subspace of $V$.  If $V$ is one-dimensional, this will be all of $V$, but if $V$ has dimension at least $2$, it will be a nontrivial subspace that isn't $\{0\}$ or $V$.

Answer (score 3):

It is true because $ \{ 0 \} $ is a subspace of $V$, but $ \{ 0 \} \neq V $ by assumption.

Comment: Yes, but OP already knows that and is probably excluding it from consideration, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe. But if this is excluded, his statement is wrong - just take $\mathbb R^1$ (as an $\mathbb R$ vector space).

Answer (score 1):

Disallowing the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ which you already already assume is a proper subspace, there need be no other proper subspace. Consider the 1-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R$, for example. It has no proper nontrivial vector subspace.

Comment: I think the passage *$V$ does not consist of the additive identity alone* covers up all one-dimensioned spaces.